# android layout smallest width (sw800dp) and different densities

Tags: android, layout

How can I put different resources for different dpi on ICS with the same sw800dp smallest width?

Details: There are two tablets with ICS 4.0.4. First one has 1280x800 resolution and mdpi (160) density. Second one has 1920x1200 resolution and hdpi (240) density. So in terms of smallest width they both have the same sw800dp qualifier but different mdpi/hdpi density qualifiers.

I need to have different layouts and images for these two resolutions.

So I created two directories:

> layout-sw800dp-mdpi
>
> layout-sw800dp-hdpi

I thought that each device will choose its own directory according to the smallest width AND density.
BUT both of them take resources from the same sw800dp-hdpi folder!

I'm very confused and do not know how to separate resources for that two different resolutions.

Any help is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i have the same issue with drawables. mdpi devices are getting resources from drawable-sw720dp-xhdpi

Comment: Mark Murphy registered a bug about this case in the Google bugtracker, but without any reaction from goo-guys. Here is the link: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37187

Comment: @NorthernCaptain I am stuck in the same problem, did you get any solution?

Comment: @AbdulSalamAli No, at that time this was an Android bug. I changed my logic and did changes programmaticaly (set everything in one layout and did setVisibility to the one that I needed). Google guys said that it was fixed in 4.1+, but I didn't checked.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the same layout, located in /layout/sw800dp, and create /drawable-mdpi , /drawable-hdpi to put your custom drawables, the system will apply the correct ones to each device, using the same layout. Those devices should have similar size and aspect...

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get the density:

```
float density = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

Screen height:

```
int h = 0;

Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

h = (int) display.getHeight();
```

Screen width:

```
int w = 0;

Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

w = (int) display.getWidth()
```

After that just select the correct resources.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to get display config programmatically, but how can I change layout loading behavior? Android does it himself when I call setContentView.